# Diagonlization argument: show there is no countable basis for the filter of nbhs of 0

Tags: functional-analysis, filters

[image]

> Prove also that there is no basis of nbhs of zero in this topology which is countable.

My attempt:

Idea: find a sequence of decreasing sequences (with positive elements) that converge to zero, and from there construct a new sequence that yield a contradiction.

Suppose that $\mathcal{B}=\{B_k\}_k$ is a countable basis for the nbh-filter $\mathcal{F}(0)$. Then we know that $$ \forall k\ge 1: \exists \{ \varepsilon_n^{(k)}\}_n \text{ decreasing, converging to zero}:\mathcal{U}(\{\varepsilon_n^{(k)}\})\subseteq B_k.$$ The goal is now to find  some $\{\xi_n\}_n$ such that $\forall k: \mathcal{U}(\{\varepsilon_n^{(k)}\})\not\subseteq \mathcal{U}(\{\xi_n\}).$ (Unless there is another way?) Why? Well, this would imply that no $B_k$ is contained in $\mathcal{U}(\{\xi_n\})\in\mathcal{F}(0)$, contradicting the definition of filter basis.

Now, how do I proceed from here on? I believe that $\{\xi_n\}$ must be constructed from the $\{\varepsilon_n^{(k)}\}_n$'s, but with the additional requirements that it is decreasing and converging to 0.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve $\def\U{\mathscr U}\def\eps{\varepsilon}\U((\xi_n)) \not\supseteq \U((\eps_n^{(k)}))$ we will construct $(\xi_n)$ such that $\xi_k < \eps^{(k)}_k$ for each $k$. To this end, choose your favorite $0<\xi_1 < \eps_1^{(1)}$ and, inductively, after $\xi_k$ is chosen, let $\xi_{k+1}$ such that $0<\xi_{k+1} < \min \{\xi_k, \eps_{k+1}^{(k+1)}\}$.

Then, $(\xi_n)$ is as wished, therefore $\U((\xi_n)) \not\supseteq \U((\eps_n^{(k)}))\supseteq B_k$ for each $k$ and $\mathscr B$ isn't a basis. Therefore $\mathscr F_c(\mathbf N, \mathbf C)$ does not have a countable basis of neighborhoods of zero.

Comment: I was wondering why $\mathcal{B}$ is not a basis. Couldn't we have that $\mathcal{U}((\xi_n))$ is contained in some $B_k$?

Comment: You are right ... I mixed up some $\supseteq$, $\subseteq$. Will correct.